# Spring MVC Restful Multipart Form Not Working

Tags: java, spring-mvc, multipartform-data, spring-rest

I've created a Restful service with Spring MVC as shown below.  I called it using Postman.  I placed a breakpoint on 'return "hello World"'.  There's no hit on the breakpoint with the error message "Required request part 'file' is not present".

However, if I comment out the '@RequestParam("file")' annotation, the breakpoint is hit with the parameter "file" being null.

What could have gone wrong?  Very puzzled.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/dp")
public class DpWebService implements IDpWebService {
    @Override
    @Bean
    public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
        return new MultipartConfigElement("");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(1000000);
        return multipartResolver;
    }

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(path = "/send", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    public String sendManifest(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Postman
[image: postman]
Postman Header
[image: postman header]

Answer (score 0):

`@RequestParam` might not be working for you because of the nature of the data that is contained in the file that you are sending through the request. **RequestParam is likely to be used with name-value form fields**. For complex data like `json/xml` it is advisable to use `@RequestPart` instead.
Instead of the `@RequestParam` annotation use the `@RequestPart` annotation.

> Annotation that can be used to associate the part of a
> "multipart/form-data" request with a method argument.

Try using it like :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/dp")
public class DpWebService implements IDpWebService {
    @Override
    @Bean
    public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
        return new MultipartConfigElement("");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(1000000);
        return multipartResolver;
    }

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(path = "/send", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    public String sendManifest(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Also make sure that the request from the postman is getting triggered correctly :

1. Remove any un wanted request params from postman.
2. Make sure that under 'Body' tab the form-data is selected. Also make
   sure that when selected the file in the key the name is provided as
   'file' and type is also selected as file instead of text.

Comment: You're only changing RequestParam to RequestPart right?  The problem still persists.

Comment: My thought was that in the txt file you were having complex data like a json which might cause problems for the RequestParam but it seems to the problem with how you make the request from postman. Could you please share the headers that you are setting in postman . Make sure that in postman the content type is multipart form-data and that you select the file using the selector in postman properly. @Tan

Comment: Hi, I've edited the post and added my Postman Header image.

Comment: Hi should it be getMultipartResolver() instead of multipartResolver()?

Comment: @Tan Empty all the headers that you have set manually, clear any un necessary params that you have set, go to the 'Body' tab and set content type as form-data. Then continue to select the file necessary using the file picker on the ui. In the screenshot provided I see that you have set something in the params tab which may not be required.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your patience.  The params are emptied as requested, the headers that are set manually are also removed, the rest of the headers are default headers.  Still the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your POSTMAN request Configuration. I think you have not changed the input type to File from Text. Uploading images, check the images. Hover the mouse over that area in Postman and select File from the drop-down menu.[image: Default Selection]

[image: Select File from the dropdown and in Value Select the actual file]

2. Having Beans defined in your RestController is not a good design. Please separate out a Configuration class with @Configuration annotation and define your beans. The reasons being: Single Responsibility Principle - each class should only do about one thing.
   https://java-design-patterns.com/principles/#single-responsibility-principle

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Regarding point (1) both input type "file" and "text" do not work.  As per my postman image, it's a "file" and that does not work.  Regarding point (2), does the bug lie here?  If not, I'll refactor the code after the bug is fixed.

Comment: Once you select type as File from the dropdown: the Value lets you browse and select a file. Did you try doing that?

Answer (score 0):

This is my working example.

```
@PostMapping("/uploadFile")
public UploadFileResponse uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    
    String fileName = fileStorageService.storeFile(file);

    String fileDownloadUri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().path("/downloadFile/")
            .path(fileName).toUriString();

    return new UploadFileResponse(fileName, fileDownloadUri, file.getContentType(), file.getSize());
}
```

application.properties

```
    ## MULTIPART (MultipartProperties)
# Enable multipart uploads
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
# Threshold after which files are written to disk.
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
# Max file size.
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=200MB
# Max Request Size
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=215MB

## File Storage Properties
# Please change this to the path where you want the uploaded files to be stored.
file.upload-dir=C://Users//abc//Documents//
```

[image: Postman File Upload]